# Magento 2 GitHub version different to installed version

Tags: magento2

I am trying to debug an issue and looking at Magento 2 on https://github.com/magento/magento2 have noticed that it is different to the version I have installed.

In the folder "**app**" I only have 2 folders "**design**" and "**etc**" however the Github version has 4 folders - `"code", "design", "etc" and "i8n"`.

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first version of magento 2 which include all core modules in `/app/code/` folder but after that Magento released new version which has lots of changes, even in structure.

Magento 2.1 : all core modules moved to vendor directory.

**i18n**  is also not in Magento 2.1 which is used for translation directory.

Download latest version of magento from magento site :
https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Comment: The bug I am correcting is https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/9515999f75fc728084079b8aae7ccc784cd8c1f3 - how do I apply this to my installation?

Comment: whatever you are applying in your installation just put that code into your code modules which are in vendor directory, they have just changed structure not logic.

Comment: It says to edit app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js but I can't find this in the "vendor" directory?

Comment: In latest magento this placed in `/vendor/magento/` all core modules, you can find your magento theme module in this directory

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/magento/magento2 
The link you provided is a developer version.
They are maintaing two version of Magento, developer and stable.
You can find the stable version here:- 
https://magento.com/tech-resources/download